# Where is the location of the file that stores Mac keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

This file is used to edit or add special shortcuts that don't appear in the Mac menu bar or System Preferences. Some examples:

> Ctrl-b → Move back one character
> Ctrl-f → Move forward one character
> Option-b → Move back one word
> Option-f → Move forward one word

Editing this special shortcut text file made these commands work throughout all Mac applications. No issues still works! **However, I am unable to locate this file's path again now that some time has passed. I want to fiddle with it some more.**

**Hints:**

- Plain text file.
- The file in somewhere in **~/Library**. No idea on the name.
- **Not** looking for the System Preferences keyboard shortcuts.
- **Not** the same file that stores the System Preferences keyboard shortcuts. **(hard-part)**
- Editing this file will change the shortcut across all Mac applications, e.g. Safari, Notes, Finder, Pages, etc. This won't effect 3rd party apps. This behavior is desirable.

Comment: Can’t grep help you find the file?

Comment: Great suggestion, but I do not know the filename.

Comment: `grep` stands for  'Global Regular Expression Print', so you need to know the string you are looking for and not filename. You could navigate to `~/Library`and search recursively for `Ctrl-b' or whatever entries you have made to special shortcut text file.

Comment: Wow that is a good idea! I feel silly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa text system keybinding defaults:

> The standard key bindings are specified in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/StandardKeyBinding.dict

To override Cocoa text keybindings:

> ...create a file named DefaultKeyBinding.dict in ~/Library/KeyBindings/ and specify bindings to augment or replace the standard bindings. You may use the standard bindings file as a template. It is recommended that you use the Property List Editor application to edit a bindings dictionary. You may use another application such as TextEdit or Xcode, but if you do you must ensure the encoding of the saved file is UTF8.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html