# Is there a command-line tool to define a keybinding on the fly?

Tags: macos, keybindings

I'm aware of some of the options for keybindings, but as far as I know none have a command-line interface.

I would like something where I can say something like "`mac-bind command-option-b <some command>`".

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87619/where-are-keyboard-shortcuts-stored-for-backup-and-sync-purposes - trouble is, the prefs are binary files, not text. Otherwise you could probably define `defaults`. There's also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400967/where-is-the-location-of-the-file-that-stores-mac-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you, but using this method I don't see how to map to a command,  this seem to work only for menu items.

Comment: Then you need to define more accurately exactly what you mean by 'command'.

Comment: calling an executable

Comment: Then no, it's not possible natively.